# How modify sphere mesh in an animation with shape keys

Tags: animation, mesh, subdivision-surface, displacement

I would like to start from a sphere/ellipse, move its vertices in order to obtain an irregular body.
The problem is that I want to create an animation of the vertices movement.
The starting model and final one are shown in the following figure
[image]

Comment: You may try a controlled Fluid Simulation to create your mesh.  The simulation will be taking over vertex placement.  This may or may not suit you.  Of course you may also try texture displacement.

Comment: You can do it easily with shape keys if you don't change the number of the verts. Why do you want to change it?

Comment: How can I do it with shape keys?

Comment: FFeller can you write the procedure with shape keys?

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use a [Displace Modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/deform/displace.html#displace-modifier) and *apply it as a shapekey*.

[image]

First add a [Subdivision Surface Modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/subdivision_surface.html#subdivision-surface-modifier) followed by the [Displace Modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/deform/displace.html#displace-modifier) and then a second Subdivision Surface Modifier.

Your modifier stack should look like the image below:

[image]

The texture can be anything grayscale, but for this example I used the below:

[image]

Once you are happy with the result of the texture you choose, apply the first Subdivision Surface Modifier, and apply the Displace Modifier *as a shape key*.

[image]

The remaining Subdivision Surface Modifier will not be able to be applied, and shouldn't be anyway.